# Grunt, warning when building jQuery

Tags: jquery, module, gruntjs

I'm getting the following warning when trying to build jQuery with Grunt:

`"Warning: You need to run this command from the toplevel of the working tree. Use --force to continue."`

My project is structured like this and I'm running grunt from within the jquery folder:

/myProject
     /components
          /jquery

If I go up a few folders to /myProject and run `grunt` I get:

`"Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue."`

Running `grunt --gruntfile components/jquery/Gruntfile.js` doesn't do much good either.

What am I doing wrong?

I've got grunt-cli v0.1.6 + grunt v0.4.0rc5 installed.  I've also installed all the jquery npm dependencies.

Comment: Why you trying to run the jQuery grunt tasks? What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: I'm trying out Bower and used it to install jQuery 1.9.0 into my /components directory.  From there I just need to build a copy of jQuery to use on my site.

Comment: You should not need to build jQuery to use it on your site -- just reference the jquery.js (or jquery-min.js) script file from the same place you load other javascript files and then use it. But perhaps you mean that you are building a jQuery plugin? Or perhaps you need to include jQuery for some QUnit tests? I think you need to clarify the question...